# Visual studio 2012 not able to open new website, 'ok' button disabled

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, web-development-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MLUM.png)

Hi, Im new to Visual studio. Started web development..not able to. 'OK' button is disabled as shown in above pic...could anyone help me to proceed..

File->new->website-> 'OK' button disabled.

Answer (score 0):

you have to select location that where your project will save, 
select browse and select your location that where you want to save your project, 
and then press ok,, if you select your project location correctly, you should able to click ok button to start your new project :)

Comment: Thank you so much for patronage Tanvir...But that is not working either... 'Visual c#' templates are missing..I think I have to install few extra files..